# Cómo hacer peticiones POST en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, post

El problema es que yo al realizar la petición esta me la hace bien, pero solo recoge los datos, si la petición es 200, si por ejemplo es 500 esta no recoge la respuesta de la petición y se me hace imposible saber el error que da para solucionarlo.

Hago la conexión:

```
   URL url = new URL(web);
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();//establece la conexion
            http.setReadTimeout(1500);//Avisa si el tempo de conecxion a pasado
            http.setConnectTimeout(1500);
            http.setRequestMethod(method);
            http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "aplication/json");
```

Le paso los datos:

```
  http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            http.setDoOutput(true);//solo en caso de peticion post o put
            Uri.Builder params = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("cpostal", codigoPostal)
                    .appendQueryParameter("email", email)
                    .appendQueryParameter("genero", genero)
                    .appendQueryParameter("localidad", localidad)
                    .appendQueryParameter("name", nombre)
                    .appendQueryParameter("pais", pais)
                    .appendQueryParameter("password", password)
                    .appendQueryParameter("password_confirmation", passwordConfirm)
                    .appendQueryParameter("provincia", provincia)
                    .appendQueryParameter("surname", apellidos)
                    .appendQueryParameter("fecha", String.valueOf(new String[]{"year:" + year, "month:" + month, "day:" + day}));


            OutputStream os = http.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(http.getOutputStream()));
            bw.write(params.build().getEncodedQuery());

            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
            http.connect();
```

y aquí recojo la respuesta de la petición

```
  String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    content += line;

            }
```

Comment: Podrias mirar el [tour] para saber como funcionamos??? tu pregunta esta muy bien estructurada...

Comment: Abrir el buffer sólo leería el cuerpo de la respuesta... y un error 50x o 40x sólo devuelve un encabezado, el cuerpo va vacío.

Answer (score 2):

para recoger la respuesta de un error, lo podrías manejar con excepciones, o también parsear el resultado que te envía el endpoint. Es decir, lo que te devuelve el endpoint, extraer el tipo de error mediante un parseo.

Algo como lo siguiente:

```
public static String getResponseFromHttpUrl(URL url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        return in.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getErrorStream()));
        return in.readLine();
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Si deseas mayor detalle, te dejo un ejemplo de como realizarlo :)

https://github.com/RaulitoGC/Udacity-Popular-Movies-Part-1/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rguzmanc/popularmovie/utils/NetworkUtils.java

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: La respuesta puede no mostrar error, entonces esto no atraparia ningun error aunque el servidor tuviera algun tipo deproblema.

Comment: Yep, se puede capturar con el Código HTTP_OK, pero en el caso que yo presentó necesito parsear lo que venga o lo que me responda, agregandolé un Timeout igual generar una excepción que también se captura. Hay diferentes maneras de resolverlo, esta es una de muchas,  pero me gusta más tu enfoque. Thanks por el comentario :)

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal es considerar la peticiòn como correcta de acuerdo a su codigo de respuesta, para esto debes usar el mètodo

[getResponseCode()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection#getResponseCode())

se considera que la peticiòn POST no tuvo ningùn problema si el valor de la respuesta es 200 (`HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK`), en base a esto realizar la obtencion de la respuesta:

```
 if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()))) {
      String line;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        // Realiza accion....
        content += line;

      }
    }
  }
```

si se obtiene otro còdigo se considera un problema en la peticiòn o simplemente un valor informativo, estos son las series de los còdigos;

```
1xx: Informational
2xx: Success
3xx: Redirection
4xx: Client Error
5xx: Server Error
```